# Spring @notation documentation

Tags: spring

Is there somewhere that shows all of the different @notations you can use for spring MVC? Having a hard time finding it.

Comment: They're part of the API, and listed by package in the javadoc, like any other class.

Comment: yes, was looking for a central repository of them all... if you dont know the name, how do you find it in the javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of them are described somewhere in the text of [chapter 15 of the Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).  However, there's no specific list of annotations in one place.  For that, one source is [DZone's Spring Annotations reference card](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/spring-annotations), from their Refcardz series (which requires registration to download).